# instance/static methods called from left to right?

Tags: java, android, methods, formatting

I'm a Java noob. When writing code that uses static or instance methods that return references to Objects, is it safe to assume that they will be run from left to right?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html (see getExternalSto... returns File)
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html (see getAbsolutePath() returns String)

i.e.

```
String storagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
```

or should you do this as a safeguard?

```
String storagePath = ( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() ).getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: What is mean of safe gurad for `String storagePath = ( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() ).getAbsolutePath();`

Comment: Both will work as same way. no need additional brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.` operator has left associativity i.e operands are grouped from left

So,yes it is safe to assume that they will be grouped from left to right

---

But what is associativity?

When  operators have same precedence,associativity governs the order in which the operations are performed..i.e from `left`(operands are grouped from left) or `right`(operands are grouped from right) or `none`

Comment: Just that associativity from left-to-right called left, not right http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity

Comment: @sandrstar ohh..yes..indeed you are right..i used it to make it clear..check out the edit

Answer (score 2):

Of course, no brackets neccessary. 
getExternalStorageDirectory() returns an object, and then you call the method getAbsolutpath() of this object.